# My mobile hamburger overlaps other submenu items

Tags: jquery, html, css

My mobile hamburger menu overlaps all other items once I click one item. 
All other items cannot be seen or clicked because of this.
 How can I fix this?

My site(use in mobile view): http://sstromberg.saldev.nl/index.html

Pictures to make it more clear:

Before: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0I6Al.jpg 
After: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqOeq.jpg

'Portfolio' and 'Overig' are gone once I click on 'CV'.

My HTML / CSS and JQuery Code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.icon').on('click', function() {
    $("#menu").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  .bar1,
  .bar2,
  .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
  .icon {
    width: 35px;
    margin: auto;
  }
  ul#menu>li {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
  ul#menu>li>ul.submenu {
    display: none;
  }
  ul#menu>li:hover>ul.submenu {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
  }
  ul#menu a:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  ul#menu {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
  }
  ul#menu a {
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    /* met 1em word de ruimte tussen de list items 2x zo groot */
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #FF4136;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .submenu {
    left: -50%;
    right: -50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hamburger-menu">
  <div class="icon">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
  </div>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li>
      <a>CV</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="pgegevens.html">Persoonlijke Gegevens</a></li>
        <li><a href="werkervaring.html">Werkervaring</a></li>
        <li><a href="opleiding.html">Opleiding</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` instead of `position: absolute;` to `ul#menu > li:hover > ul.submenu` and remove `left: -50%; right: -50%;` from `.submenu` and that should do it. When the submenu is position absolute, it doesn't take up space and goes over the menu below but with position relative, it'll take up the space and move the other menu items. Make sure to do this in a media query that targets only the mobile menu, because the desktop menu needs the `position: absolute;` on the submenu.

Comment: That did it, thanks!

Two more questions: 1. How do I prevent that the menu opens on default when I open a page? I'd like to have it that it only opens when I click the hamburger icon.

2. How can I do it so when I click on a menu item, 'CV' for example, the submenu items under 'CV' disappear when I click on CV again?  
A picture again to make it more clear: https://imgur.com/a/j6MaK

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: you have to do something like css - display:none, on your menu or li, then javascript a onclick display:block when they click on your burger.  There are various tutorials online

Comment: 1. To hide the menu on page load, add `display: none;` to `ul#menu;` in the mobile media query. The jQuery click even will override that with `display: block;` when needed.

Comment: 2. You currently have the submenu show up on hover but it's best to do it on click, at least for the mobile menu. It would be something like this: `$('#menu a').on('click', function() {
  $(this).siblings('.submenu').slideToggle();
 });`

Comment: You solved my problems that I was trying to solve for days!

Thanks! @pavger